# Begun or began?

Tags: past-tense

whether to use begin began or begun seems to be well covered, but i'm wondering which feels natural or better, had begun or had began when talking about someone doing something.

Comment: While not wanting to cloud the situation further, but I think the "natural" feel of it may well be down to a regional dialect.  Personally Begun sounds more natural, but placing different accents over the sentences give different feels.

Comment: *begun* is the form used for the perfect tenses. [Here's a comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+began%2Chad+begun&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20began%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20begun%3B%2Cc0). As for the "natural feeling", that could be down to dialects as @Chris hinted at: you'll certainly find regional dialects in which the two forms are pronounced nearly identically

Answer (score 1):

This might give some sort of an idea of their use:

1. *I had begun to...*
2. *I began to...*

Usually "begun" is prefaced with "had".

In use, an example of each would be:

1. *The others had begun to write when I dropped my pen.*
2. *The teacher said it was time to start the test, and everyone began to write.*

Comment: Thanks. Would it be begun or began if worded had already began to, because there the word already is after had, does this break the rule?

Comment: @Will It would be _had already begun to_. "begun" follows "already" which in turn follows "had". Does that make sense?

Comment: Would there be any circumstances where began is correct in this instance? or if not correct, useable? thanks @wd7

Comment: Possibly in the instance of _He already began writing._

Comment: Kudos.  appreciate the answers @wd7

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!

Comment: *He already began writing* doesn't sound right. I can't think of any context in which that works. However, if someone were to say *"But I already began writing!"* it sounds fine.